# C# reference comparison

Tags: c#, image, reference, comparison, marshalling

Does someone know what might go wrong, when you attempt to compare two `System.Drawing.Image` entities?

I have some `IEnumerable<Image> images`, which is constructed iteratively using `Image.FromFile(path)` method.

*But the following code yields the result I can't quite understand:*

```
foreach (var image1 in images)
{
    foreach (var image2 in images)
    {
        if (image1 == image2)
        {
            // (Do something!)
        }
    }
}
```

*The thing is that the `(Do something!)` part never gets called.*

Debugger shows that the image objects have a property called `nativeImage`, which, as I assume is a raw memory pointer, because `System.Drawing.Image` is implemented using marshalling.

This **memory pointer** is changed all the time and I guess some sort of cloning happens here, but I can't understand what should I actually do.

**What am I doing wrong and how can I actually compare `System.Drawing.Image` objects taken from one `IEnumerable<>` sequence to see if they are the same?**

Thank you.

---

## Update

```
        var paths = new List<String> {"Tests/1_1.jpg", "Tests/1_2.jpg"};
        IEnumerable<Image> images = paths.Select(path => Image.FromFile(path)).ToList();

        foreach (var image1 in images)
        {
            foreach (var image2 in images)
            {
                if (ReferenceEquals(image1, image2))
                {
                    
                }
            }
        }
```

***Without the `ToList()`, this obviously didn't work, I'm very stupid.***

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Are any of the images you are comparing actually the **same** images?

Comment: @giddy Yep, I checked with two images with different dimensions. *So, obviously, they point to the same images but are treated as different objects.*

Comment: Interesting... I just did this exercise and the //(Do Something!) line got hit once for every image in the list.  All I did was load up list of png images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that each time you call `GetEnumerator` you will see new objects returned for each call to `MoveNext`. What you need to do is force the iteration into a list.

```
var imageList = images.ToList();
```

Comment: Yep, that's where I f*ked up. Thank you very much)

Answer (score 1):

By `image1 == image2` you're only comparing the references of the image (not image as pixel by pixel).

By invoking `Image.FromFile(path)` you create new image object every time you call this method (even if the path is the same) so they always have different references.

I don't know if there is a method to compare images pixel by pixel, but of course you can implement your own mechanism for it (it doesn't look difficult).